# Need help sending class and VF page to production

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, code-coverage, controller-extension

I am unable to get an apex class into production from my sandbox

I assume it is because i have not written any tests

Could someone help me write some tests for this class so i can get it over to production for my demo tomorrow?

The apex class and VF page use 4 text boxes to create a "Physician's Note". There are only 4 boxes and 1 save button

My code is pasted below:

```
public with sharing class AddPhysicianNoteExtension
{
    public Physicians_Note__c note { get; private set; }
    public AddPhysicianNoteExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // this constructor must be defined to add the extension to the page
        Id accountId = controller.getId();
        note = new Physicians_Note__c(Account__c=accountId);
    }

    public PageReference save()
    {
        try
        {
            insert note;
        }
        catch (DmlException dmx)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessages(dmx);
        }

        Return Null;
    }
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AddPhysicianNoteExtension">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Physician's Note" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="SOAP Note" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField Label="Subjective" value="{!Note.Subjective__c}" style="width:500px"/>
            <br></br>
            <apex:inputField Label="Objective" value="{!Note.Objective__c}" style="width:500px"/>
            <br></br>
            <apex:inputField Label="Assessment" value="{!Note.Assessment__c}" style="width:500px"/>
            <br></br>
            <apex:inputField Label="Plan" value="{!Note.Plan__c}" style="width:500px"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Edit: This is my class thus far:

```
@isTest
public class Physicians_Note_test_Class{
    Static Void Physicians_Note_Test();
Physicians_Note__c PhysicianNote1 = New Physicians_note__c(Subjective__c = 'This is a subjective Test', Objective__c = 'This is an objective Test'
,Assessment__c = 'This is an Assessment Test', Plan__c = 'This is a Plan Test');
}
```

Comment: Nothing XD

I am very new to this, reading up on the process right now but it's hard for me to write these from scratch

Comment: I've formatted your code properly. The Stackexchange network uses a variant of a formatting style called 'markdown' to format questions (and answers). Formatting something as a block of code (as you'd do for a class, or a visualforce page) requires that each line have at least 4 spaces at the very beginning. The easiest way to format code here is to copy/paste your class/method/fragment, highlight it, and then press `ctrl + k`.

Comment: Community team members can code for you, and its quite easy. But if you really know the process to write a test class, you would no longer need additional help and it'd help in longer run. Suggest you to go through some documentation like this super awesome [trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro). And feel free to ask for help if you are stuck in particular place.

Comment: I am having trouble interpreting the trailhead and changing it to fit my use case. Not really sure how to supply a negative test if there is no real way to fail (being free text)

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to get the basic syntax right. Every test should look something like:

```
static testMethod void testSomeMethod()
{
    // set up data

    Test.startTest();
        //execute some method
    Test.stopTest();

    // assert on behavior
}
```

So, you need to at least start with that template. Your entire test class might then look something like:

```
@IsTest
class AddPhysicianNoteExtensionTests
{
    static testMethod void testConstructor()
    {
        // same template as above
        // assert on note being properly set up
    }

    static testMethod void testSave()
    {
        // same template as above
        // assert on note being properly inserted
    }
    static testMethod void testSave_Error()
    {
        // same template as above
        // assert on error handling behavior
    }
}
```

Now, how do you instantiate your extension? Three steps:

1. Insert an `Account` record.
2. Instantiate an `ApexPages.StandardController` with this record.
3. Instantiate your extension with this controller.

Basically your setup process will look like:

```
// Step 1
Account record = new Account(/*required fields*/);
insert record;

// Step 2
ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(record);

// Step 3
AddPhysicianNoteExtension extension = new AddPhysicianNoteExtension(controller);
```

For your constructor test, step 3 would come between `startTest` and `stopTest`. For the other tests, it would come before `startTest` (it's just setup). Your other tests will add a fourth step, calling the `save` method.

```
// set up extension as above

Test.startTest();
    extension.save();
Test.stopTest();
```

For your error case, you can cause a `DmlException` by setting the `Id` value on the `note` before calling `save`.

```
// set up extension as above

Id dummyId = SObjectType.Physician_Note__c.getKeyPrefix().rightPad(15, '0');
extension.note.Id = dummyId;

Test.startTest();
    extension.save();
Test.stopTest();
```

Keep in mind that the most important aspect of testing is to assert on application behavior. For the above tests, you need to make sure:

- Your constructor instantiates `note` as a non-null value.

  ```
  system.assertNotEquals(null, extension.note,
      'The note record should be constructed');
  ```
- The constructed `Physician_Note__c` record actually looks up to the `Account`.

  ```
  system.assertEquals(record.Id, extension.note.Account__c,
      'The note record should look up to the Account');
  ```
- The `Physician_Note__c` record will get inserted when you save (re-query from the database).

  ```
  system.assertNotEquals(1, [SELECT count() FROM Physician_Note__c],
      'The note record should be inserted');
  system.assert(ApexPages.hasMessages(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM),
      'A confirmation message should be added to the page');
  ```
- If your save fails, the errors will get added to the page.

  ```
  system.assertNotEquals(1, [SELECT count() FROM Physician_Note__c],
      'The note record should have failed to insert');
  system.assert(ApexPages.hasMessages(),
      'The error messages should be added to the page');
  ```

Comment: You'll notice that a lot of this content is laid out in a way that it's not the easiest to copy-paste. Copy-paste programming is *not* your friend when you are learning, in my opinion.

Comment: +1 Its like a custom trailhead module tailored specifically for this question, No idea on how you do that, really appreciate your efforts!